# SSH timeout on connection

Tags: ssh, vpn

## Context

- Recently I have changed my ISP for a fiber offer.
- Also my MacBook Pro got an update to macOS Catalina.
- I use iTerm2

*I did not use SSH since few months, so I don't know if my issue comes from one of this change or not at all...*

## My problem

Today I wanted to push a git repository to Gitlab.com but I was not able to connect over SSH.

After some test, I tried to do it again using a VPN (TunnelBear). All of a sudden, it worked.

## What I tried

I don't know if the issue comes from my laptop or my internet box.

Just to make sure the issue was not coming from Gitlab, I tried to connect  to [free public SFTP](https://www.sftp.net/public-online-sftp-servers), for example to [demo.wftpserver.com](http://demo.wftpserver.com). The same behavior happen here also.

So, I tried the following command :
`ssh -vT demo-user@demo.wftpserver.com -p 2222`

- When I'm using a VPN, [here are the logs](https://pastebin.com/FiTmgtVk).
- When I'm not using a VPN, [here are the logs](https://pastebin.com/j3UbNeU6).

The only difference happens at the end, there is some kind of timeout when I'm not using a VPN.

Same test when I'm running : `ssh -vT git@gitlab.com`

- [Logs when it works](https://pastebin.com/fSc0GXKt) (using VPN)
- [Logs when it does not work](https://pastebin.com/L4Ltdc3R) (no VPN)
- [Diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/x7epOB8n)

## My question

How can I evaluate where the issue is coming from, my laptop or my ISP or my internet box ?

## Update

I tried to connect using another internet connection (my smartphone using Hotspot). It work great, **so the issue must come from my internet box**. How to know what to do ?

---

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

From what you've told here, it seems like it is an issue with the traffic being blocked by the ISP. They might have a firewall blocking ssh, most likely by blocking port 22.

**What you can try:**

1. Contact the customer support, and find if they are willing to open
   the port.

But more likely to succeed:

2. Use port 443 to connect instead.

Gitlab should have port 443 open for situations like this, according to: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/

The link also gives a guide for how you would need to change your ./ssh/config if you don't know how to already.

Hope this helps,

-, Emil

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already but my box is connected to a wifi router (D-Link DIR-600) and I am connected to the DIR-600. I tried to open 443 and 22 TCP ports on my box for the DIR-600 routeur but this doesn't work. I will contact them, the problem comes from them obviously

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess I would say there is a problem with path MTU discovery. Definitely something to raise with your ISP customer support.